# SUM Product along with MOD and Column formula in Excel Table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have around 30 columns and in the 27th column, I would like to use the below-mentioned formula:

`"=SUMPRODUCT(--(RC[-22]:RC[-1]),--(MOD(COLUMN(RC[-22]:RC[-1]),2)=1))"`

The above-mentioned formula is a recorded one, but I would like to use a **dynamic formula** as the **columns get added and sometimes deleted**. I tried different ways of editing the recorded formula. I'm unable to understand where I'm going wrong. The below-mentioned code is what I have tried:

```
Dim OLC As ListObject
Dim FirstName As String
Dim LastName As String
IndMetricsSht As Worksheet

Set OLC = IndMetricsSht.ListObjects(TableName)

Set IndMetricsSht = ActiveSheet

FirstName = IndMetricsSht.Cells(1, 5)

LastName = IndMetricsSht.Cells(1, IndMetricsShtHeaderCount - 3)

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(" & IndMetricsSht.ListObjects(TableName) & [@[FirstName]:[LastName]] & "),--(MOD(COLUMN(" & IndMetricsSht.ListObjects(TableName) & [@[FirstName]:[LastName]] & "),2)=1))"
```

Please help me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `[@[` and `]:[` and `]]` in `[@[FirstName]:[LastName]]` will need to be surrounded in quotes and concatenated in with `&`.

Comment: Hi @BigBen, that worked for me. Thanks a ton!. I have a small question, the above-mentioned formula is replicating in only a single cell in that column, How do I make that formula to replicate the entire column at one go?

Comment: Write the formula to an entire range in one step, instead of using `ActiveCell`.

Comment: Sure @BigBen, thanks a lot! :)

Here's the final formula-change that worked:

   `IndMetricsSht.ListObjects(TableName).ListColumns("Total Errors").DataBodyRange.Select`
    



`Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(" & IndMetricsSht.ListObjects(TableName) & "[@[" & FirstName & "]:[" & LastName & "]]),--(MOD(COLUMN(" & IndMetricsSht.ListObjects(TableName) & "[@[" & FirstName & "]:[" & LastName & "]]" & "),2)=0))"`

Comment: Sure @BigBen I'll do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this question:

The `[@[` and `]:[` and `]]` in `[@[FirstName]:[LastName]]` will need to be surrounded in quotes and concatenated in with `&`.

The final formula:

```
"=SUMPRODUCT(--(" & IndMetricsSht.ListObjects(TableName) & "[@[" & FirstName & "]:[" & LastName & "]]),--(MOD(COLUMN(" & IndMetricsSht.ListObjects(TableName) & "[@[" & FirstName & "]:[" & LastName & "]]" & "),2)=0))"
```